# Draw a semi circle in mapbox Gl ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

i need to draw a semi circle in my reactjs web map. I'm using mapbox library, but i dont find anything about how draw a semi circle.

Here's one example of how I did it in the mobile app:
[The exemple while is on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Kysn.png)

The light blue indicates the area that our product can cover according to the information at the time of installation, dark blue indicates where the product has been since it was turned on and the white flag indicates where our product is currently.
I just need to draw  the dark blue semi-circle, it just can't be an image, because the initial and final angles will change, the radius is also a fixed value that I get from the server, but it must be centered on a specific coordinate. The dark blue section is superimposed on the light blue as it will not always be displayed as the equipment may be turned off, as the following [Off exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUFqt.png)

Comment: Semi-circle of what? Collection of lng/lat points, an image, something else?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I edit the promblem and show some examples